# XML Parsing error: XML parsing: line 1, character 169, equal expected

Tags: sql-server, xml

Hi i am getting XML Parsing error in the following string.

How to find the error .

```
<ControllerSetupData>
    <MasterSetupData ControllerId="0" ControllerModelId="1" ControllerTypeId="2"
        EcolabAccountNumber="040242802" TabId="0" TopicName="test 78" Factors Multiplier="10"
        ControllerNumber="78" OZSecondMultiplier="10" InjectionQuantityMultiplier="10"
        InstallDate="05/02/2016" Active="false"/>
    <DynamicSetupData>
        <Data ControllerId="0" ControllerModelId="1" FieldGroupId="6" FieldId="21"
            Value="10.225.134.21.1.1" FieldTagValue="" EcolabAccountNumber="040242802"/>
        <Data ControllerId="0" ControllerModelId="1" FieldGroupId="6" FieldId="79" Value="78"
            FieldTagValue="" EcolabAccountNumber="040242802"/>
    </DynamicSetupData>
</ControllerSetupData>
```

Comment: Please share the XML and the script you are used for parsing, otherwise how can one predict the solution?

Answer (score 2):

In your XML at

```
<ControllerSetupData>
    <MasterSetupData ControllerId="0" ControllerModelId="1" ControllerTypeId="2"
        EcolabAccountNumber="040242802" TabId="0" TopicName="test 78" Factors Multiplier="10"
                                                                      ^^^^^^^
```

The attribute name `Factors` must be followed by `=` and a value

Comment: Or this is, in fact, not XML but just something that closely resembles XML (and as such, the OP shouldn't expect an XML parser to process it)